# how to perform precopy memory migration in LXC /LXD so that I can perform live migration from one host to another

Tags: migration, containers, lxc, lxd

how to perform precopy memory migration in LXC /LXD so that I can perform live migration from one host to another?How do I set to precopy migration in CRIU?

Answer (score 1):

The [Pre-copy memory migration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Live_migration#Pre-copy_memory_migration) for [Live migration with CRUI](https://criu.org/Live_migration)

[Live Migration of Linux Containers between hosts (there is migration script)](https://tycho.ws/blog/2014/09/container-migration.html), [LXC and CRUI](https://criu.org/LXC):

> You should have built and installed a recent (>= 1.3.1) version of
>   CRIU.
>
> LXC upstream has begun to integrate checkpoint/restore support through
>   the lxc-checkpoint tool. This functionality has been in the recent
>   released version of LXC---LXC 1.1.0 , you can install the LXC 1.1.0 or
>   you can check out the development version on Ubuntu by doing:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-lxc/daily
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install lxc
```

And add the following lines (as above) to LXC container config:

```
cat | sudo tee -a /var/lib/lxc/u1/config << EOF
# hax for criu
lxc.console = none
lxc.tty = 0
lxc.cgroup.devices.deny = c 5:1 rwm
EOF
```

checkpoint the container:

```
lxc-checkpoint -s -D /tmp/checkpoint -n u1
```

At this point, the container's state is stored in /tmp/checkpoint, and the filesystem is in /var/lib/lxc/u1/rootfs. You can restore the container by doing:

```
lxc-checkpoint -r -D /tmp/checkpoint -n u1
```

PS:
You can do live migration for processes:

**Dump**
Take tasks you're about to migrate and dump them into some place, asking `criu` to leave them in stopped state after dump:

```
criu dump --tree <pid> --images-dir <path-to-existing-directory> --leave-stopped
```

The directory you put images to can reside on the shared file-system if you're using one. In this case you can skip the Copy step and proceed to Restore.

**Copy**
Copy images to destination node:

```
scp -r <path-to-images-dir> <dst>:/<path-to-images>
```

**Restore**
Go to the destination node and restore the apps from images on it:

```
criu restore --tree <pid> --images-dir <path-to-images>
```